# Дух сделал из ссылок на ХэшКод битые ссылки на ruSO

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дух-сообщества, хэшкод

Наткнулся на [такую правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/359328/3):

[image]

При попытке открыть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/answer_link/294616/ получил ошибку 404

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky почему так задумано-то?

Comment: Это не дефект движка, а скорее дефект (если дефект) скрипта импорта базы данных. Я вижу [8 таких вопросов](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/770504). Обновление: готово, поправил их все.

Answer (score 3):

Она там и была битая. Исправил на нормальную заменой `/answer_link/` на `/a/`.

Comment: То есть на хэшкоде она тоже не работала что ли?

Comment: Редирект с хэшкода на ruSO работает до сих пор, Дух поменял в соответствии с редиректом - можешь попробовать открыть старую ссылку. Но в этом месте формат различался по какой-то причине.

Comment: Собственно о том и [дефект] — нужно было поменять формат. Гугл находит ещё как минимум две «answer_link» ссылки, поэтому одна правка в общем-то проблему не решает, нужно научить Духа автоматически исправить свои косяки везде :)

Comment: @andreymal, тут уже не дух, а сама миграция, вероятно. Потому что дух взял ссылку и верно её поменял, а уж то, что она уже была неверной - это не его проблема. Я нашёл [ещё одну](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/322615/178988) - поправил.

Comment: Ну, миграция виновата разве что в том, что замену ссылок не провели сразу же в 2015-м) А теперь, раз уж приспичило духу поменять ссылки в 2017-м — пусть он ответственность и несёт :D